# How to fix this issue with multiple lines in charts

Tags: ios, swift, charts, ios-charts

I'm trying to show my data in charts, but I have issue when I try to do that with multiple lines. The lines behave strangely, I tried many things, but I could not fix it in any way. Here is a picture of this

[image: Charts]

I'm using Xcode(Version 10.1 (10B61)), Swift 4.2, Charts 3.2.1

```
let dollars1 = [1453.0,2352,5431,1442,5451,6486,1173,5678,9234,1345,9411,2212]
let dollars2 = [5641.0,2234,8763,4453,4548,6236,7321,3458,2139,399,1311,5612]
let dollars3 = [6541.0,3456,7843,5678,5877,7323,7111,6456,5143,4562,6311,10412]

var yVals1 : [ChartDataEntry] = [ChartDataEntry]()
for i in 0..<dollars1.count {
    yVals1.append(ChartDataEntry(x: dollars1[i], y: Double(i)))
}

let set1: LineChartDataSet = LineChartDataSet(values: yVals1, label: "First Set")
set1.axisDependency = .left // Line will correlate with left axis values
set1.setColor(UIColor.red.withAlphaComponent(0.5))
set1.setCircleColor(UIColor.clear)
set1.lineWidth = 2.0
set1.fillAlpha = 65 / 255.0
set1.fillColor = UIColor.red
set1.highlightColor = UIColor.yellow
set1.drawCircleHoleEnabled = false

var yVals2 : [ChartDataEntry] = [ChartDataEntry]()
for i in 0..<dollars2.count {
    yVals2.append(ChartDataEntry(x: dollars2[i], y: Double(i)))
}

let set2: LineChartDataSet = LineChartDataSet(values: yVals2, label: "Second Set")
set2.axisDependency = .left // Line will correlate with left axis values
set2.setColor(UIColor.green.withAlphaComponent(0.5))
set2.setCircleColor(UIColor.clear)
set2.lineWidth = 2.0
set2.fillAlpha = 65 / 255.0
set2.fillColor = UIColor.green
set2.highlightColor = UIColor.yellow
set2.drawCircleHoleEnabled = false

var yVals3 : [ChartDataEntry] = [ChartDataEntry]()
for i in 0..<dollars3.count {
    yVals3.append(ChartDataEntry(x: dollars3[i], y: Double(i)))
}

let set3: LineChartDataSet = LineChartDataSet(values: yVals3, label: "Third Set")
set3.axisDependency = .left // Line will correlate with left axis values
set3.setColor(UIColor.blue.withAlphaComponent(0.5))
set3.setCircleColor(UIColor.clear)
set3.lineWidth = 2.0
set3.fillAlpha = 65 / 255.0
set3.fillColor = UIColor.blue
set3.highlightColor = UIColor.yellow
set3.drawCircleHoleEnabled = false

//3 - create an array to store our LineChartDataSets
var dataSets : [LineChartDataSet] = [LineChartDataSet]()
dataSets.append(set1)
dataSets.append(set2)
dataSets.append(set3)

//4 - pass our months in for our x-axis label value along with our dataSets
let data: LineChartData = LineChartData(dataSets: dataSets)
data.setValueTextColor(UIColor.white)

//5 - finally set our data
self.lineCharts.data = data
```

Comment: You swapped your x and y values. `yVals.append(ChartDataEntry(x: dollars[i], y: Double(i)))` should be `yVals.append(ChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: dollars[i]))`

Comment: Tom Knapen thanks, but values isn't my problem. The red and blue lines in attached image sometimes disappear, sometimes appear.

Answer (score 0):

Iam using SwiftChart git library :- https://github.com/gpbl/SwiftChart

click to see in image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2Iof.png)

here is the code :-

```
let chart = Chart(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 100))
let series = ChartSeries([0, 6.5, 2, 8, 4.1, 7, -3.1, 10, 8])
chart.add(series)
```